# Cross-site duplicate questions

Tags: support, questions, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/691/how-do-we-perceive-and-read-words-and-sentences-does-the-order-of-the-inner-lett) was asked recently; it was pointed out that it is fundamentally similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/is-it-true-that-only-the-positions-of-the-first-and-last-letter-in-a-word-matter) on English Language & Usage SX.  Given this:

- Is there a way to vote to close a question as a duplicate of a question on another site?  The software rejects trying to enter the URL from another SX in the "duplicate question" field.  Given the natural overlap of this site and EL&U, I think this is functionality we will need in the future.
- (relatedly) Is there an established mechanism of merging answers on two sites?  The Linguistics version of the question has already garnered some useful answers which it would be nice to consolidate with the EL&U version of the question.

(Note, I am not asking about whether it would be appropriate to take these actions; that is another discussion that is taking place in the comments at that question, and someone can raise here if they want.  I am merely asking if it is technically possible to do these things.)

Comment: since this question is not SE-specific perhaps you can ask the meta.SO?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that even if it was possible, we should "dupe" this one. It's the same question but under a different point of view.

About your last note, I wanted to say something. Like I've stated in [another question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/651/whats-the-official-term-for-when-a-word-is-at-the-tip-of-your-tongue/655#655)'s comments, I think we should allow psycholinguistics questions.

Apart from specific questions, I'm talking in general: I'm not saying all of them are actually on topic, because we must consider that there's also psychology in it. But when it treats about linguistics, I think we can not ignore it. This is the only Linguistics site, if we don't allow it, I don't know who would.

I can agree if we want to set some boundary, but cutting it off completely like that just isn't the thing to do, that's what I think. There's really some pretty interesting stuff in that field (although I'm not actually an expert in it), it might be a waste to cut it off.

Comment: psycholinguistics - OK. That question - not psycholinguistics. OK maybe a sliver, but that wasn't a question, just a 'look -at-this-it's-neat-whaddya-think' statement.

Comment: Eheheh you mean the rdeanig question?

Comment: uh...yes...the "rdeanig" question I thought off-topic but not the TOT question (full bias acknowledged!).

Comment: The topic was interesting, honestly, and I've also heard about it before today, but I never went into the matter. Maybe it was just badly/poorly formulated?

Comment: @mitch i watched the TOT question, and IMHO this is clearly cognitive psychology, similar to the deja-vu phenomenon, memorizing. I dont see how you can draw conclusions from this concerning linguistics. My question is a phenomenon directly related to redundancy/structure of language, recognizing of morphems to be able to read a word...I think you should make it clearer in the FAQ. In my question on Capitalization you also say it is off-topic? Despite 5 upvotes. So i think the german philologists have some serious scientific pros & cons to prescribe Capitalization of every noun. Its no dicing.

Comment: @Hauser same I said under [my answer](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/158/psycholinguistics-or-psychology-of-language-on-or-off-topic/159#159) in the [psycholinguistics on or off topic](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/158) question.

Answer (score 4):

Though the questions are the same, the audience including the answerers are not the same.

On English Language & Usage it will attract answers considering only English and not the interesting stuff here about other languages which for me redeemed the whole question.

On English Language & Usage most people are concerned with usage and what is correct, when people there try to cover linguistics topics they are not always well informed. Here we have more linguists and people who know at least some linguistics basics and who are often because of that less interested in correct usage but know more about deeper issues.

When I saw the question I thought "hmm this isn't what the site is about". But when I read the answers I found some surprising and enlightening results, and for me that's what linguistics is about so I discovered that the question, with its answers, did belong here after all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with hippietrail, the same question can be asked in different SEs and have different answers because the different points of view. Either they are allowed here (and will generate different answers) or they are closed as off-topic and no merging should be done.

[Edit] Just realised that you specifically do not ask whether it is appropiate. The easiest way I can think of is to migrate the question to the other SE and do the duplicate marking and/or merging there. But our SE doesn't have any migration path now.